# Sub-domain forwarding (unconditional/wildcard)

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, forwarding, domain-name, wildcard-subdomain

I would like to forward all requests for *domain.net* to *domain.com*. The forwarding works only for the top level URL, meaning the server redirects *domain.net* to *domain.com*.

However, any and all sub-domains requests fails; for example, *domain.net/sub/content.html* would simply pop a **NOT FOUND** page. There are **many** such sub-domains, and links to them have been well-propagated through the past five years. Creating individual forwarding scripts for each and every one of them would be very unproductive.

Is there any way to catch such sub-domain requests for *domain.net* and simply forward them all to one specific sub-domain page in *domain.com*?

For example:

*domain.net/sub1/content.html*  **=>** *domain.com/netpage/index.html*

*domain.net/sub2/content.html*  **=>** *domain.com/netpage/index.html*

*domain.net/**  **=>** *domain.com/netpage/index.html*

Thank you.

**EDIT:**  *Both the domains and their contents are on a shared webhost (Site5), running Apache servers.*

Comment: What is the web server? Apache has various URL rewriting modules available, for example.

Comment: Those are not subdomains, but subfolders under the same domain (just a definition problem)
The solution will be different depending on which daemon/service are you running the requests. Apache? Nginx? IIS? Ligthttpd?...

Comment: Hello, and thank you for the quick replies. It's a shared web host running Apache.

Comment: And yes, they're in subfolders, but each needs to be redirected to a separate domain; _domain.net_ to _domain.com_.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you're trying to do correctly and the domains are pointing to the same web server (ip address) then perhaps this solution might be for you?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837978/apache-multiple-sub-domains-with-one-ip-address